# Copy a std::atomic<float> outside the part of the code, where it is parallely accessed

Tags: c++, c++20, stdatomic

I know that `std::atomic<float>` is not copy-constructible and I know that there is a very good reason for this. However, I have an object of the following form

```
class atomic_value_type
{
public:
    atomic_value_type() = default;
    atomic_value_type(atomic_value_type const& other)
        : m_data{ other.m_data[0].load(), other.m_data[1].load(), other.m_data[2].load() }
    {}

    constexpr std::atomic<float>& operator[](std::size_t const i) { return m_data[i]; }
    constexpr std::atomic<float> const& operator[](std::size_t const i) const { return m_data[i]; }

private:
    std::array<std::atomic<float>, 3> m_data;
};
```

I have multiple threads working on an object of this `atomic_value_type`. After the threads are done, I simply need to return this object to the calling function. I've implemented this wrapper of a `std::array<std::atomic<float>, 3>` to achieve this, but is this wrapper really necessary? And should I really use `load()` or better `load(std::memory_order_relaxed)`? Or should I care about this at all? (Performance of the code is crucial for me, which is why I'm worried about this)

Comment: If performance is crucial (also in the non-parallel section), then you can look at [`std::atomic_ref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_ref), which allows you to use the object as an atomic object during the parallel section and as a non-atomic object outside of it. (However, if the non-parallel section isn't synchronized to happen before or after the parallel one, then you'll have UB. Also, the requirement to take care of proper object alignment yourself makes this a bit more risky to get wrong. See link for the details.)

Comment: @user17732522 Thank you for your comment. The non-parallel section happens *after* the return of the function, where the parallel access is happening. Do I still need synchronization then?

Comment: You need happens-before synchronization between your parallel and non-parallel parts. e.g. from `thread.join`, or from an `acquire` load on a flag updated by the parallel part.  A function returning within one thread doesn't imply any of that.  But if you do have that, then you can safely do non-atomic accesses to objects the parallel part was making atomic accesses to.  You just need to be sure there isn't still some thread that could be accessing `std::atomic_ref<float>(m_data[i])` while you're doing it.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Presumably the function blocks in some form in order to wait for all involved threads to finish their part of the work, either by `join` or e.g. a `condition_variable` or something else. These should imply sufficient synchronization, but to be sure, it depends on the details of that function.